# Htaccess RewriteUrl characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am trying to make a PHP wiki for my own use, and have an Apache mod_rewrite rule to make `/Main_Page` go to `/index.php?title=Main_Page`

The code is below:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?title=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?title=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?title=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?title=$1
```

However, I am stuck on something. I'd like the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` part to accept any  character, not just alphanumeric ones.
Is this possible? If so, how would I manage to do it?

Comment: `[:punct:]` - http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm might be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A period will match any character except a newline.

Comment: Just to be safe, put a [^/] instead of a period. It will match any non-slash character.